# What's the difference between connection and connect, and when should I use one over the other?

Tags: python, peewee

I'm using peewee extensively with the `play_house.db_url.connect` to connect to a database. This method allows for a lot of flexibility and it is very straightforward when opening a single connection to a database i.e., open and close a single connection.

However, this gets unclear when attempting to reuse the Pooled versions of the URL. For instance, if I do:

```
from playhouse.db_url import connect

db_url = 'postgresql+pool://...?max_connections=20&stale_timeout=300'
db = connect(db_url)
```

what is db ?? a single connection or a connection pool? in case it is the later, how do I from a multi-threaded application e.g. Flask, acquire a separate connection from the pool? using [connect](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.connect) or [connection](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.connection)? which one and why?

or do I instead, every time I need a new connection should do over again? or is this creating a new separate pool?

```
db = connect(db_url)
```

and if so will calling `db.close_all()` apply to all the opened connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above, `db = connect(...)`, `db` is just a database instance. The database instance manages the connections.

Example code:

```
db = connect('postgresql+pool....')
# At this point no connections are opened.

# Now open a connection.
db.connect()

# Now call close() -- this will return the connection to the pool.
db.close()

# Calling connect again will use the conn from the pool.
db.connect()
```

When your application has multiple threads, peewee will automatically ensure you have a connection-per-thread:

```
# thread 1:
db.connect()  # Open a connection.

# thread 2:
db.connect()  # Opens a separate connection.
```

Read the docs on connection management for more details, http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#connection-management

Comment: thanks a lot, this is very helpful. I believe you throw `MaxConnectionsExceeded` exception when the max capacity is reached, is blocking until a connection is available something that the client code should cover? alla Producer-Consumer pattern

Comment: You can specify a long `timeout` but it usually indicates a problem in the application if you have too many connections open, so I don't recommend it. Postgres, for instance, can bog down if it receives too many connections - MySQL may be better, but you still likely don't want 100's of them.